Atlas Search C# patterns for building search query dynamically
I’m working on an application which has ONE search input value (one search text box)  and it should be able to perform the following type of searches.

Normal text search
Phrase search
Logical AND/OR
Miss spelled words
Wildcard search

The search logic will be developed in C#. My questions are:

What’s a good pattern/practice to use to design/model a class that will be able to dynamically build the search query on the fly based on the type of search being performed. Any simple example would be appreciated.

What's the best method to differentiate between the type of searched being performed by the user


